# How to add a new Struct column to a DataFrame

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark, etl, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently trying to extract a database from MongoDB and use Spark to ingest into ElasticSearch with `geo_points`.

The Mongo database has latitude and longitude values, but ElasticSearch requires them to be casted into the `geo_point` type.

Is there a way in Spark to copy the `lat` and `lon` columns to a new column that is an `array` or `struct`?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I assume you start with some kind of flat schema like this:

```
root
 |-- lat: double (nullable = false)
 |-- long: double (nullable = false)
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
```

First lets create example data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val rdd = sc.parallelize(
    Row(52.23, 21.01, "Warsaw") :: Row(42.30, 9.15, "Corte") :: Nil)

val schema = StructType(
    StructField("lat", DoubleType, false) ::
    StructField("long", DoubleType, false) ::
    StructField("key", StringType, false) ::Nil)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

An easy way is to use an udf and case class:

```
case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)
val makeLocation = udf((lat: Double, long: Double) => Location(lat, long))

val dfRes = df.
   withColumn("location", makeLocation(col("lat"), col("long"))).
   drop("lat").
   drop("long")

dfRes.printSchema
```

and we get

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lat: double (nullable = false)
 |    |-- long: double (nullable = false)
```

A hard way is to transform your data and apply schema afterwards:

```
val rddRes = df.
    map{case Row(lat, long, key) => Row(key, Row(lat, long))}

val schemaRes = StructType(
    StructField("key", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("location", StructType(
        StructField("lat", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("long", DoubleType, false) :: Nil
    ), true) :: Nil 
)

sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddRes, schemaRes).show
```

and we get an expected output

```
+------+-------------+
|   key|     location|
+------+-------------+
|Warsaw|[52.23,21.01]|
| Corte|  [42.3,9.15]|
+------+-------------+
```

Creating nested schema from scratch can be tedious so if you can I would recommend the first approach. It can be easily extended if you need more sophisticated structure:

```
case class Pin(location: Location)
val makePin = udf((lat: Double, long: Double) => Pin(Location(lat, long))

df.
    withColumn("pin", makePin(col("lat"), col("long"))).
    drop("lat").
    drop("long").
    printSchema
```

and we get expected output:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- pin: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- long: double (nullable = false)
```

Unfortunately you have no control over `nullable` field so if is important for your project you'll have to specify schema.

Finally you can use `struct` function introduced in 1.4:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

df.select($"key", struct($"lat", $"long").alias("location"))
```

Comment: Thanks @zero323 for your thorough answer! This helps a bunch. Would you know how I could do this mapping recursively for nested types? This data is uglier than I hoped.

Comment: I  don't see any reason why you couldn't.

Comment: Hi @zero323 - Do you know if there is anyway to use your UDF method of creating a struct if there is more than 10 columns in the new struct?  UDFs seem to have a limitation on 10 input variables.

Comment: @PatrickMcGloin  Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/39494620/1560062 help?

Comment: Hi @zero323.  Actually your last suggestion of the "struct" function helped me.  I should have read to the bottom first!

Comment: @zero323 any advice how to solve this in spark ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933135/dataframe-look-up-and-optimization

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.registerTempTable("dt")

dfres = sql("select struct(lat,lon) as colName from dt")
```